# ContentPlaceHolder is outside the table

Tags: asp.net, contentplaceholder

I put a ContentPlaceHolder of my MasterPage in a table, and it shows outside the table.

Someone to help me ?

Thank you

```
<table class="four_tile_table" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
       <td class="feature_phone_content" valign="top" width="39%">
          <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
          </asp:contentplaceholder>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You've got something else going on here. Placeholders work just as expected for me.

Comment: it shows outside the table!!means?

Comment: I add border to my table and I see that the content of the ContentPlaceHolder is outside the border

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `contentplaceholder` assumes the size of its contents, so if you want to size the contents, wrap your inner content with a table of a particular size.

Also, do you have the same problem if you wrap your `contentplaceholder` inside the `<div>`? (Hint: use `position:relative`)

Comment: Ok sorry I was my mistake, I was referring to an another ContentPlaceHolder... :shame:

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Float: right or left in your stylesheet?

Comment: if I remove any style of my page, the problem is still here

Comment: how are sure that its displaying outside the table? I dont see a header of something for the table to distinguish it

Comment: Because it's outside the border the table (border=1)